# PHP not generating random number on Ajax reload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, web

For a web project I've been developing, I need to surf through an XML file, grab some SimpleXML objects and store them in an array, then get a random SimpleXML object and print some info about it.

I've got that part finished, and it works - but only when I load the page by itself.
When I try to load it in another HTML page through jQuery's `$('#div').load('somescript.php');` method, I always end up getting the same results, dus to PHP's `rand()` always yielding 0.

What could be the problem here? Running the exact same script in its own browser tab by itself will give me random results (which is what I want), but loading it inside another page with jQuery and Ajax gives me the same result.

**What's causing the problem here?**

Here is my code if it helps:

**GetBandData.php**

```
<?php
$ChosenGenre        = "edm";
$AlreadyLoadedBands = False;                                // Set to True if we've already loaded the array of bands to show the user.
$BandsToShow        = array();                              // The final array of bands to show the user.
$XMLRoot            = simplexml_load_file('artists.xml');   // The root of all XML queries.

if ($AlreadyLoadedBands == False){                  // If the bands haven't already been loaded into an array...
    foreach($XMLRoot->band as $ThisBand){           // Iterate through the XML database, looking at all the bands.
        if ($ThisBand->genre == $ChosenGenre){      // If the band's genre and the user's chosen genre match up...
            array_push($BandsToShow, $ThisBand);    // Add the current band to the array of bands to look at.
        }
    }
    $AlreadyLoadedBands = True;                     // "Okay, we've already loaded the bands. No need to do it again."
}

$RandomBand = rand(0, count($BandsToShow) - 1);     // Set $RandomBand as a random integer between 0 and the amount of bands we've found.

// Set $BandImLookingAt's indexes to a bunch of data about the band in the $RandomBand-th index of $BandsToShow.
$BandImLookingAt = array(
                            "BandName"      => $BandsToShow[$RandomBand]->name,
                            "BandSafeName"  => $BandsToShow[$RandomBand]->codesafe_name,
                        );
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($BandImLookingAt);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**artists.xml**

```
<root>
<band>
    <genre>edm</genre>
    <name>Chainsaw Police</name>
    <codesafe_name>chainsawpolice</codesafe_name>
</band>

<band>
    <genre>edm</genre>
    <name>Guerrilla Warfare</name>
    <codesafe_name>guerrillawarfare</codesafe_name>
</band>

<band>
    <genre>edm</genre>
    <name>SPENDV</name>
    <codesafe_name>spenda</codesafe_name>
</band>

<band>
    <genre>edm</genre>
    <name>Byzanite</name>
    <codesafe_name>byzanite</codesafe_name>
</band>

<band>
    <genre>edm</genre>
    <name>Hawf</name>
    <codesafe_name>hawf</codesafe_name>
</band>

</root>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function recp() {
      $('#myStyle').load('GetBandData.php');
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="recp()" >One</a>
<a href="#" onClick="recp()" >Two</a>
<a href="#" onClick="recp()" >Three</a>

<div id='myStyle'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

or tape on a random number to the `GetBandData.php?{{random}}`

Comment: That last solution seems pretty nifty! but for my purposes, the first solution worked fine enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function recp() {
  $('#myStyle').load('GetBandData.php?_'+Math.random());
}
```